# New Item not displaying properly in-game

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

I've created my first weapon (**item ID: 90000 | display ID: 42070**) using *Keira*. I restarted the DB and clear the cache on the client. I spawned the weapon onto my character, but I get a question mark in the inventory. When I equip the weapon and the character is attacking I can see the weapon , but when it is sheath I can't see the weapon.

I've looked at several conversations that speak about patching the client, but its way over my current pay grade. I need to learn how to do this if I want to continue to create content. Where can I go to learn the skills that I am missing? or who can teach me how to fish so that I can fish for myself? Please advise...

~ ***tinywolf***

Answer (score 1):

You can do a workaround on this by changing a weapon that is already in the game in Keira3

Unless u have created a completely new model u maybe just wanna change another that already has the look